# Get text inside buttons when pressed using only one event handler

Tags: vb.net, button

I'm making a simple calculator. I'm tired of assigning event handler in every button, It is inefficient.

I want only one event handler to get the text inside a button when pressed.

How to do that?

```
  Private Sub num1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles co.Click
    numPressed = num1.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: can you share your codes?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? I don't think you could couple your presentation to your implementation any more if you tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your click event:

```
Dim button as Button = sender
Dim theTextYouWant as String = button.Text
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add all the events you want to handle with a function, and detect inside which button has ben pressed:

```
Private Sub num1_Click(sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
Handles co.Click, co2.Click, co3.Click 'etc
    Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    numPressed = btn.Text
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can efficiently add handle your `button's click event` during runtime like this,

I assume that you are having your `buttons` inside a `panel` called `PnlBtns`.

```
'Traversing through panel and adding a common handler for buttons
For each ctrl in PnlBtns.controls
 If TypeOf ctrl is button then
   AddHandler ctrl.Click, AddressOf CommonClickHandler
 end if
Next

'Common Handler for all of your buttons.
Private Sub CommonClickHandler(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
  MsgBox(ctype(sender,button).text)
End Sub
```