# Handling all textbox event in one Handler

Tags: vb.net

I do know how to handle event of textboxes in my form. But want to make this code shorter because I will 30 textboxes. It's inefficient to use this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox2.TextChanged, TextBox3.TextChanged, TextBox4.TextChanged, TextBox5.TextChanged, TextBox6.TextChanged, TextBox7.TextChanged, TextBox8.TextChanged, TextBox9.TextChanged, TextBox10.TextChanged
    Dim tb As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)

    Select Case tb.Name
        Case "TextBox1"
            MsgBox(tb.Text)
        Case "TextBox2"
            MsgBox(tb.Text)
    End Select
End Sub
```

Is there a way to shorten the handler?

Comment: I think you asked this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336379/get-text-inside-buttons-when-pressed-using-only-one-event-handler) yesterday and got some answers too..!

Comment: I'm looking for the most shortened version ^_^

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Controls.OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) +  [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) programmatically. For example:

```
Dim textBoxes = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
For Each txt In textBoxes
    AddHandler txt.TextChanged, AddressOf txtTextChanged
Next
```

one handler for all:

```
Private Sub txtTextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim txt = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    Select Case txt.Name
        Case "TextBox1"
            MsgBox(txt.Text)
        Case "TextBox2"
            MsgBox(txt.Text)
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I think,the select statement is not necessary here, instead we can write a single line like this `MsgBox( DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Text)` :)

Comment: @GLOIERTECH.: I have just copied OP's code, i assume that's just sample code and he actually wants to handle these cases differently. I wanted to show that it's possible to identify the original `TextBox`(although OP was already aware of it).

Comment: Ok :) , I'm New to this site, and i had been seeing many of the people here are using the word called 'OP' what is that mean?(full form)

Comment: Here's an overview(incl. OP): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms and here specifically to OP: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79804/whats-stackexchange-ese-for-op

Answer (score 3):

Say If you are having that 30 `textboxes` inside a panel(`PnlTextBoxes`), Now you can create `handler` for your `textboxes` dynamically like this below

```
For each ctrl in PnlTextBoxes.controls
 If TypeOf ctrl is TextBox then
   AddHandler ctrl.TextChanged, AddressOf CommonClickHandler
 end if
Next


Private Sub CommonHandler(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

      MsgBox(ctype(sender,TextBox).Text)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have created very Textbox with the Designer, I don't think there is a better method.

But, if you have created the Textboxes dynamically, you should AddHandler in this way:

```
For i = 0 to 30
    Dim TB as New Texbox
    AddHandler TB.TextChanged, TextBox1_TextChanged
    'Set every Property that you need
    Me.Controls.Add(TB)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The *best* way would be to inherit from `TextBox`, override its [`OnTextChanged` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.ontextchanged.aspx) to add your custom handling code, and then use that on your form(s) instead of the built-in `TextBox` control.

That way, *all* of the event handling code is in one single place and you increase abstraction. The behavior follows and is defined within the control class itself, not the form that contains the control. And of course, it frees you from having a bunch of ugly, hard-to-maintain `Handles` statements, or worse, slow and even uglier `For` loops.

For example, add this code defining a new custom text box control to a new file in your project:

```
Public Class CustomTextBox : Inherits TextBox

    Protected Overridable Sub OnTextChanged(e As EventArgs)
        ' Do whatever you want to do here...
        MsgBox(Me.Text)

        ' Call the base class implementation for default behavior.
        ' (If you don't call this, the TextChanged event will never be raised!)
        MyBase.OnTextChanged(e)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then, after you recompile, you should be able to replace your existing `TextBox` controls with the newly-defined `CustomTextBox` control that has all of your behavior built in.