# Detecting the ID of checkbox that was checked

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows

I am making a windows form application. I want to detect which checkbox is being selected by the user. One way to check this would be to loop through all the controls everytime a checkbox `checkchanged` event is fired. But I do not want to do that because multiple checkboxes could be checked. I want to get the ID of checkbox as it is selected or on a mousedown event. How can I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the event handlers for the checkboxes you want at runtime. Use the `Where` clause to filter by name if applicable. This code does it in form_load.

Inside the handler, you can cast `sender` to a local variable which represents the checkbox which was checked, if you want.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each checkBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)().Where(Function(cb As CheckBox) cb.Name.Contains("CheckBox"))
        AddHandler checkBox.CheckedChanged, AddressOf checkboxCheckedChanged
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub checkboxCheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim myCheckbox As CheckBox = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)
    Dim c As Boolean = myCheckbox.Checked
    Dim n As String = myCheckbox.Name
    ' etc.
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

As Neolisk pointed out, this doesn't account for nested controls, i.e. controls inside containers on the form. This extension method returns all those controls:

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function ChildControls(Of T As Control)(ByVal parent As Control) As List(Of T)
    Dim result As New List(Of Control)
    For Each ctrl As Control In parent.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is T Then result.Add(ctrl)
        result.AddRange(ctrl.ChildControls(Of T)())
    Next
    Return result.ToArray().Select(Of T)(Function(arg1) CType(arg1, T)).ToList()
End Function
```

And make this the loop in form_load instead:

```
    For Each checkBox In Me.ChildControls(Of CheckBox).Where(Function(cb As CheckBox) cb.Name.Contains("CheckBox"))
        AddHandler checkBox.CheckedChanged, AddressOf checkboxCheckedChanged
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sender` argument in the event handler.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                                                 Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
  'DirectCast(sender, CheckBox).Name ?
End Sub
```

Comment: I have a small doubt,why the handle clause contains checkbox1.checked I mean this function should handle for all checkboxes so how this function will be invoked when some other checkbox is ticked

Comment: @user2179293: This is standard syntax generated by Visual Studio, I dropped a CheckBox onto a form and double-clicked on it. In your case you can have multiple events handled by the same event handler, static or dynamic. You may or may not have static Handles clause - the approach does not change. You will still need to examine the `sender` argument.

Comment: In case of handling multiple checkboxes do I have to enumerate the names of all checkboxes after handle. I have around 200 check boxes

Comment: @user2179293: No, you don't. `sender` will be the CheckBox you checked.

Comment: @user2179293 You can programatically add the handler to each CheckBox's CheckedChanged event: [AddHandler Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx). Doing that for a load of controls: [Handling all textbox event in one Handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358338/handling-all-textbox-event-in-one-handler).

Comment: @user2179293: In case you don't already know this, you can further reward answers by upvoting them.  A typical practice here on StackOverflow is to accept and upvote answers that are most helpful. Remember, you can upvote as many answers as you like, but only one can be accepted.