# AllTextBox event in TextChanged

Tags: vb.net

Hello This is a code of mine

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    TextBox1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    TextBox2.Text = Val(TextBox2.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged
    TextBox3.Text = Val(TextBox3.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox4_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox4.TextChanged
    TextBox4.Text = Val(TextBox4.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox5_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox5.TextChanged
    TextBox5.Text = Val(TextBox5.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox6_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox6.TextChanged
    TextBox6.Text = Val(TextBox6.Text)
End Sub
```

How do i make a short code for all textboxes ?
I try with this code i didn't work

```
 Dim i As integr
    TextBox(i).text = Val(TextBox(i).text)
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Make all your textboxes use the same event handler, use the sender parameter as your textbox for the Val, then drop the VisualBasic compatibility library and use the NET methods (int32.TryParse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to create one TextChanged handler and then bind all your Texbox events to it.

```
Private Sub TextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox2.TextChanged, <...for all your textboxes ..>
    Dim target = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    target.Text = Val(target.Text)
End Sub
```

If you want to bind all textboxes in code, you can do this programatically once your form has loaded:

```
Dim allTextBoxes = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
For Each textbox In allTextBoxes = 
    AddHandler textbox.TextChanged, AddressOf TextBox_TextChanged
Next
```

Comment: C# syntax for variable type here: `TextBox target = sender as TextBox`

Comment: Thanks for Answer but i have 35 textbox It's pain to write TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox2.TextChangedTextBox3.TextChanged, TextBox4.TextChanged and so on any small piece a code

Comment: Fix the C# blunder - sorry @ProGrammer. I have added code to programtically bind all Textboxes.

Comment: Dug this up too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358338/handling-all-textbox-event-in-one-handler

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft Nice answer

Answer (score 2):

Use one handler for all:

```
Private Sub TextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)  Handles TextBox1.TextChanged, _
                                                                           TextBox2.TextChanged, _
                                                                           TextBox3.TextChanged, _
                                                                           TextBox4.TextChanged, _
                                                                           TextBox5.TextChanged, _
                                                                           TextBox6.TextChanged
    Dim txt = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    txt.Text = Val(txt.Text)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Murray Foxcroft's answer. You could dynamically create the Handler for the textboxes and add the subroutine for their code in one by doing

```
Dim textboxes = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
For Each txt in textboxes
    AddHandler textbox.TextChanged, Sub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                                       ... (using sender to find out which textbox sent the command)
                                    End Sub
Next
```